# How to pass data from two textfield to Jeditorpane as html?

Tags: html, textfield, jeditorpane

I try to retrieve data from database and populate it in the Jlist. After that, when I click the Jlist, the data will be populated to 3 textfields. Two of them will be populated to a Jeditorpane as a combination in the form of a html file. I have tried the following method but it creates an error.

```
String meaning1 = txtMeanings.getText();
String source1 = txtSources.getText();
String htmlText = "<html>"
        + "<body>"
        + "<div class='content'>{meaning1}</div>"
        + "<div class='footer'>{source1}</div>"
        +"</body>"
         + "</html>";
JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane_1.setBounds(10, 40, 529, 387);
    panel_2.add(scrollPane_1);

     HTMLEditorKit hed = new HTMLEditorKit();
        StyleSheet ss = hed.getStyleSheet();
        ss.addRule("BODY {...}");
        ss.addRule("h1{...}");
        ss.addRule("p{...}");
        ss.addRule("blockquote{...}");
        ss.addRule("#title{...}");
        ss.addRule("hr{...}");
        ss.addRule("#content{ ...}");
        ss.addRule("#footer{...}");
        Document doc = hed.createDefaultDocument();

        editorPane = new JEditorPane();
        editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
        editorPane.setEditorKit(hed);
        editorPane.setDocument(doc);
        editorPane.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane_1.setViewportView(editorPane);
ListboxEntry.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {

            try
    {
        String query ="select EntryLists, Meanings, Sources from Entry where EntryLists like ? ";
        PreparedStatement pst=Connection.prepareStatement(query);

        pst.setString(1,(String)ListboxEntry.getSelectedValue());
        ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();


        while(rs.next())
        {
            txtEntry.setText(rs.getString("EntryLists"));
            txtMeanings.setText(rs.getString("Meanings"));
            txtSources.setText(rs.getString("Sources"));

        }

        pst.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}



             editorPane.setText(htmlText);
        }
    });
```

What should I do? Is is possible to populate two data (meaning and source) directly to Jeditorpane without populating it first in the two textfield? In the VB.Net, I solve the problem simply by putting this simple code:

```
 WebBrowser1.DocumentText = String.Format("<html><head><style><!--body{{....}}--></style></head></head><body><div id=content>{0}</div><div id=footer><b>Notes:<br></b>{1} </div></body></html>", txtMeanings.Text, txtSources.Text)
```

How to do that in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I solve my own problem by changing to the following code:

```
ListboxEntry.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {

        try
{
    String query ="select EntryLists, Meanings, Sources from Entry where EntryLists like ? ";
    PreparedStatement pst=Connection.prepareStatement(query);

    pst.setString(1,(String)ListboxEntry.getSelectedValue());
    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();


    while(rs.next())
    {
        txtEntry.setText(rs.getString("EntryLists"));
        txtMeanings.setText(rs.getString("Meanings"));
        txtSources.setText(rs.getString("Sources"));

    }

    pst.close();
    rs.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();}
String htmlText = "<html>"
    + "<body>"
    + "<div class='content'>"+ txtMeanings.getText() +"</div>"
    + "<div class='footer'>"+ txtSources.getText() +"</div>"
    +"</body>"
     + "</html>";

         editorPane.setText(htmlText);
    }
});
```

But, if anyone wants to improve it, your suggestion is welcome.